# Limiting Display Frame Rate to Lower

Tags: adb, root-access, stock-android, sony-xperia, terminal

Is in Android there is an available database set for limits display frame rate? If they’re available, is using ADB/Root (Terminal), or how, or even it can't?

I've been searching this for years, and not get an answer yet. Actually, this is for tweaking to trigger any benefits. This like my other phone embedded feature is Xperia STAMINA mode which is it can set the display frame rate (to 2x lower from 30 fps) for battery saving. But... I mean is not only for that. Many others too that can benefit. So, is this can available on a pure Android system? Or this only self-made for manufacture's hardware so that not possible available on others except Xperia devices?

If there are other threads that I don't know. Please let me know. I'll understand it, and try if it makes sense.

thank you! :D

Comment: [On one Plus phones](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-google&ei=ytDmX_7VJ4ml9QPU5rG4BQ&q=reduce+one+plus+display+frame+rate&oq=reduce+one+plus+display+frame+rate&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAM6BAgAEEc6BAgeEAo6BAghEApQtVZY1XJgj4EBaABwAngAgAGzAYgB_AaSAQMwLjaYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 13 had a feature to lower the frame rate called Game Mode interventions. However, it is only limited to games app category, and not system-wide work.

Some manufacturers may use this feature or remove it. As well as developers should declare Game Modes as false on Manifest file. Otherwise, the platform will ignore the configurations and only use in-game optimizations.

Also, this feature may require a newer GPU, and a supported display frame rates.

---

**To view the existing package configuration:**

```
adb shell device_config get game_overlay <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

---

**To set game mode interventions configuration:**

```
adb shell device_config put game_overlay <PACKAGE_NAME> <CONFIG>
```

Parameters example:

```
adb shell device_config put game_overlay <PACKAGE_NAME> mode=2,fps=90:mode=3,fps=30
```

Parameters details:

- `mode=2` for performance mode, and `mode=3` for battery mode.
- `fps` value are device specific: `30`, or `60` for 60 Hz displays; `30`, `45`, or `90` for 90 Hz displays; and `30`, `40`, `60`, or `120` for 120 Hz displays; else, any attempt of any other value than the device specified value, will cause the device to crash. `fps=0` is the default value.

---

**To switch the game mode from the configured package:**

```
adb shell cmd game mode performance <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

OR

```
adb shell cmd game mode battery <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

OR

```
adb shell cmd game mode standard <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

---

References:

[FPS throttling | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/games/gamemode/fps-throttling)

[Game Mode interventions | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/games/gamemode/gamemode-interventions)

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way at this time.

So far, all I know is a hidden feature in Android S Preview Revision 3, namely Game Optimization in the Game menu which can lower frame rates, such as Xperia STAMINA mode.

---

Portal: [Android 12 DP3 Analysis: Here are all the hidden features! | xda-developers.com](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-12-dp3-hidden-features/)

Screenshot: [17-Game-Mode-2.jpg (563×1155) | xda-developers.com](https://www.xda-developers.com/files/2021/04/17-Game-Mode-2.jpg)

Learn more: [Android Developers | developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/)